# How to change the list item color its clicked

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

How to change the list item color, when i click the list item it show the dialog box and i give some values in the dialog box it will be stored in the list item and also list item color need to changed

Comment: just change your parent view background color ........

Comment: Do you mean all list items or only the one clicked (and edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a custom layout for your listview.
2. Use a ArrayList to pass the contents to your Adapter.
3. When the item in listView is clicked, get the position of the item, and change the background of your custom layout.

Answer (score 0):

in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/red" />
</selector>
```

in  listView.setOnItemClickListener

```
listView.setSelection(R.drawable.selector);
```